# Subdomain in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps

We already have domain and webhost. Let say example.com. Included on the webhost package are our email accounts. So we have user1@example.com, user2@example.com, etc.

I want to link subdomain.example.com to ourapp.appspot.com. In adding domain in appengine dashboard, it seems it require to register for Google Apps (https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/standard/new3).

Will this be fine? Note that we already have email accounts for our example.com.

Thanks. Im confused with google apps.

Answer (score 0):

Usually I make a subdomain on my provider and insert the CNAME ghs.googlehosted.com.
Then add the domain in Google Apps(new account or as domain alias) with *.example.com or also subdomain.example.com.